# How to update certificate for Azure Service Fabric Cluster?

Tags: certificate, azure

I have Azure Service Fabric Cluster. For it I have certificate that is almost expired. So I want to import new certificate with updated issue date.

I have added it to key vaults as new version of current certificate and have added this certificate as Admin client cert for Cluster.

But...

When I go to cluster dashboard, browser ask me for certificate, I select newly installed, I goto cluster dashboard and still see old certificate in site information.

What I did wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update service fabric to use that certificate, you need to distribute that certificate to the nodes. It appears you have done the first part, but forgot the second. You can use [this cmdlet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.servicefabric/add-azurermservicefabricclustercertificate?view=azurermps-6.12.0) to distribute certificate.

Reading: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-security-update-certs-azure#add-a-secondary-certificate-using-resource-manager-powershell

Comment: Thx, yes this helps... Secondary certificate was added with mentioned cmdlet.But still have one question (haven't found answer by your link). In case I delete primary certificate, will secondary become as primary?

Comment: its automatically using the one that expires the lattest, but you need to migrate to dns names (instead of thumbprints) for that, i think